# EVault backup status outdated

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am getting the latest backup job status of the EVault agents from the API but for one job the status is outdated since the jobs are running successfully daily as has been informed by the EVault notification.

## EVault notification

```
Agent: Number 3
Job: BACKUP Daily
Retention: DAILY
Job start time: 31-Jul-2016 21:00:05 -0500
Job end time: 31-Jul-2016 21:00:30 -0500
Elapsed Time: 00:00:25
SafeSet: 00000252
```

## API call

```
SoftLayer_API['Account'].getEvaultNetworkStorage(mask='mask(SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)[virtualGuest,hardware,backupJobDetails]')]
```

## Getting from the API (take a look on lastRunDate):

```
{
    'username':'IBME657XXX-3',
    'serviceResourceName':'ev-vaultdalxxxx.service.softlayer.com',
    'id':728XXXX,
    'backupJobDetails':[
        {
            'description':'Daily backups',
            'lastRunDate':'2016-07-19T21:01:07-05:00',
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

## Expect to get from the API:

```
{
    'username':'IBME657XXX-3',
    'serviceResourceName':'ev-vaultdalXXXX.service.softlayer.com',
    'id':728XXXX,
    'backupJobDetails':[
        {
            'description':'Daily backups',
            'lastRunDate':'2016-07-31T21:00:30-05:00',
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Unsing the control portal do you get the same behavior?

Comment: I asked the customer to check in the control portal and he saw the same behavior. Also checked WebCC and there the EVault agent was offline, so the agent notifies that the backup has been made successfully but it isn't.

Comment: Looks like an issue with Softlayer and not with the API, I suggest you to submit a ticket to softlayer and asked them about that, using the API you should get the same result as the portal, but as you see the same error in the portal there is nothing wrong with your API request.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the last time that  the job ran? The content of the "backupJobDetails" property is ordered ASC, so the last time of the job ran is the last value into the "backupJobDetails" property.

Also review if you see the same wrong value in the control portal at https://control.softlayer.com/storage/evault

You only might see a little diference in the time, but that is likely due to your Evault device and your Softlayer Account have a different timezone configuration.

If you are still seeing a big diference between the time displayed in your Device and the time displayed in the Control Portal, it may be an issue and I recommend you to open a Ticket in softlayer in order they can look into that.

Regards